# referencing item in meteor mongodb with this._id

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In the code below, I am trying to get my head around this line of code
`Resolutions.update(this._id, {$set:{checked: !this.checked}});`

here is what I gather, please correct me;

update - is a method being called on a Mongodb collection.

**this._id** - [The selection criteria for the update.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)  
**this** - is the Template.body.helpers context.
**_id** - is the item in the mongodb.

**{$set:{checked: !this.checked}}** - [The update parameter](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter)
**$set:** - is a mongodb operator
**checked** - the field to update or create if no exist.
**!this.checked** - this works, but I was expecting it to be **!this._id.checked** in order to negate the value of checked.
Thanks

```js
Resolutions = new Mongo.Collection('resolutions');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.body.helpers({
    resolutions: function() {
        return Resolutions.find();
    } });

    Template.body.events({
        'submit .new-resolution': function(event) {
            var title = event.target.title.value;
            Resolutions.insert({
                title: title, createdAt: new Date()
            });

            event.target.title.value = "";
            return false;
        }
    });
    //object
    Template.resolution.events({
        //property1
        'click .toggle-checked': function(){
            //call update method on Mongo object
            Resolutions.update(this._id, {$set:{checked: !this.checked}});
        },
        //property2
        'click .delete': function(){
            Resolutions.remove(this._id);
        }
    })
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>resolutions</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="new-resolution">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="a new customer">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <ul>
        {{#each resolutions}}
            {{> resolution}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</body>

<template name="resolution">
    <li>
        <input class="toggle-checked" type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}">
        {{title}}
        <button class="delete">Remove</button>
    </li>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in this case is literally going to be one of the Resolution objects coming from MongoDB.  Your helper says return all Resolutions objects, and your template says to render a resolution template for each of them.  So an example object taking the context of `this` might be:

```
{
    "_id": "abcdefg",
    "title": "Sample Title",
    "checked": true
}
```

So when you're doing the update, what you're saying in English is:

`Resolutions.update(this._id, ...)` - Update the documents in the Resolutions collection where the internal id (_id) is equal to `this._id`.  In my example, that would be "abcdefg".  The next part describes how we'll actually be updating the documents.

`{$set:{checked: !this.checked}}` - Set the value of those documents in the Resolutions collections to have the checked property equal to the opposite of `this.checked`.  In my example above, we'd be setting the value to `false`.

The reason that you don't need this._id.checked is because of how your object is structured as I outlined above - this._id.checked would be undefined.